# Android app with Retrofit2 Crashes without error messages

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm developing an android application which needs to consume rest apis deployed, for now, on an heroku instance...since i got crashes anytime i try to integrate retrofit as http client I've done the following:

Added retrofit2 as dependendcy (didn't choose the latest version in order to avoid potential maturity problems)

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

I coded an example android app, just to check if something has been done wrong in my original app, using http://httpbin.org/ip

```
public interface HttpBinService
{
public static class Response
{
    private String origin;

    public Response(String origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public void setOrigin(String origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }
}

@GET("ip")
public Call<Response> getIp ();
}
```

And the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Retrofit setup
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://httpbin.org")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    // Service setup
    HttpBinService service = retrofit.create(HttpBinService.class);
    try {
        Call<HttpBinService.Response> call = service.getIp();

        Response<HttpBinService.Response> res = call.execute();

        if (res.isSuccessful()){
            Log.i("PROVARETROFIT", "OK");

            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.testo)).setText(res.body().getOrigin());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I did not forget to ask for internet permissions in my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.spich.provaretrofit">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

But all i got is that application closes unexpectedly. If t execute it in debug, it executes correctly all steps until call execution. LogCat appears to not say anything useful

```
04-15 09:48:08.281 6491-6491/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-15 09:48:08.367 6491-6491/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/it.spich.provaretrofit-1/lib/arm64
04-15 09:48:08.387 6491-6491/it.spich.provaretrofit I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
04-15 09:48:08.577 6491-6491/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6491 SIG: 9
```

Has someone idea of what is happening there?

Comment: remove google gson dependency

Comment: how did you figure/be sure about retrofit is making crashes? try making calback like services.enque(new Callback..)

Comment: Are you using Instant Run by chance? If you are, try disabling it.

Comment: I've added gson depencency tring to fix the problem that was present even before. Http request is never executed, nor synchronously (with execute()) nor asynchronously (with enqueue ()), executing app in debug step by step, both methods cause a "signal 9" without any exception or error message of any sort

Comment: @JasonRobinson...uhm, i don't know about this feature...

Comment: Change .baseUrl("http://httpbin.org")  to .baseUrl("http://httpbin.org/")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why logcat doesn't show anything useful. But when executing it, it is giving an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, which can explain the problem. So as they say in the comments: try using the enque method with a callback, this also allows you to get rid of the try/catch statement. Try to replace the code after `// Service setup` in your MainActivity with:

```
    HttpBinService service = retrofit.create(HttpBinService.class);
    Call<HttpBinService.Response> call = service.getIp();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<HttpBinService.Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<HttpBinService.Response> call, Response<HttpBinService.Response> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.i("PROVARETROFIT", "OK");

//((TextView)findViewById(R.id.testo)).setText(res.body().getOrigin());
                System.out.println(response.body().getOrigin());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unsuccesfull");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<HttpBinService.Response> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Call failed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great! Well, Network calls shouldn't be done on the main thread, as it simply freezes the whole app if this is done. Using this callback structure forces it to be executed on a separate thread, and thus allows the app to continue to do it's work. 

We are basically forced to execute network calls on a separate threat, which forces us not to generate apps that are freezing because of this. Your earlier code did the network call on the main thread, which throws this NetworkOnMainThreadException.